# Method Decorator in class based view is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, decorator, django-class-based-views

I am using class based view and applied permission classes only on POST method using method decorator. Till yesterday it was working but all of sudden it stopped. I am unable to find issue.

```
class OfferCreateListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer
    queryset = Offers.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)

    @method_decorator(permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)))
    @method_decorator(authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication,)))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OfferCreateListView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Where i am doing wrong. Is there any setting for this to work??

Comment: "all of sudden it stopped" isn't very descriptive...  What *does* happen? Errors?  Invalid results?

Comment: @Sayse dont know...but i am allowed to post without authentication..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `permission_classes` and `authentication_classes` decorators are designed for function based views. I haven't followed the rest framework code all the way through, but I'm surprised that it worked until yesterday -- I don't the decorators are intended to be used with class based views.

Instead, set attributes on the class. Since you only want the permission class to be applied for post requests, it sounds like you want [`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly).

```
class OfferCreateListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer
    queryset = Offers.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
```

Comment: i want to apply on POST method Not on GET method...that is the reason i used method decorator

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot that the first time I read your question. In that case, I think you want the `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` permission class.